# Disable LVDS Display on CentOS

Tags: linux, terminal, centos, kde-plasma

I have a kind of a weird problem, let me try to explain it:

I got CentOS 7 installed and I'm running a desktop environment on it (using it as a display to show a website on it, nothing big). Now when I boot it, it has 2 displays, one is the LVDS display, the other one is my hardware display, connected via VGA to a normal monitor

The problem here is that the monitor only shows the background, the LVDS seems to be the primary display. Now, I'm not that much into Linux but I know how to set the VGA display to primary.

```
xrandr --output VGA --primary
```

When I execute that command it tells me "Can't open display"
Same for using 'xrandr' only to show all displays

Now, this is the twist: When I'm on the desktop environment, I can't open any terminals. When I'm inside the VT (via CTRL+ALT+F3) xrandr seems to fail open the displays.

How else can I change the VGA display to primary? I even tried switching to HDMI or plugging in a 2nd monitor.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

xrandr on a VT fails because it can't connect to the X server.
The default address for the main X server is `:0` so you could try

```
DISPLAY=:0 xrandr
```

Comment: Tried that and it gave me the same error as usual, Can't open display :0

Comment: Maybe there is no X session running at all?

Comment: There is - when I start up the machine I get that blue background with a cursor, and when I move the cursor to the left it disappears while when I move it to the right it hits the side of the screen

Comment: Hmm, ok. You are running the xrandr command as the same user that is running the X session or as root?